# How to use directive to load an external template in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I use directive to load an external template in Angular?

Angular,

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,

        //templateUrl points to an external html template.
        emplateUrl: 'fixture/main.html'
    };
});
```

html,

fixture/main.html,

```
<div ng-controller="SimpleController">{{sayHello()}}</div>
```

Nothing is loaded. Any idea what have I missed?

Comment: emplateUrl: 'fixture/main.html', typo? emplateUrl?

Comment: oh sorry my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,

        //templateUrl points to an external html template.
        templateUrl: 'fixture/main.html'
    };
});
```

and in HTML

```
<div ng-controller="SimpleController"><div hello-world></div></div>
```